# unclickable area in top right corner

Tags: gui, workspaces, wayland, gnome-shell-extension

Sometimes an unclickable area appears in the top right corner of the screen. the area is **invisible** unless I switch workspaces, then it would appear as a small black box during the transition. everything else seems normal.

I do not know what prompts this strange effect. But judgeing by the size and location of the box I assume it is related to the extensions. I have already tried turning off my extensions and it still happened.

[image: screenshot of case]

```
❯ neofetch            
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               hasan@hasan-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-4 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: 21E30086TX ThinkPad E14 Gen 4 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.2.0-25-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 30 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2226 (dpkg), 23 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: zsh 5.9 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 44.2 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-magenta-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru-magenta [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5-1235U (12) @  
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris  
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 8960MiB / 15659MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.
I have tried running `xprop` and clicking on that region, but it didn't found ant PID related to that region.

Comment: Hasan, try looking-glass tool from gnome-shell (Alt+F2 then `lg`)? use pick tool over that box if it brings anything.

Comment: @user.dz will try it if the condition returns. it has been away for a while

Comment: Do you have anydesk installed? It sounds like this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/2018290

Comment: @Bruni yes I do have Anydesk installed. the problem has been gone for a while though.